# Displaying nested divs on the same line

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working with a react component that produces nested divs. I'd like to style force the divs to be on the same line but can only declare styles on the outer container div. Is there a way to achieve this without styling the inner divs? If only I can pass style to the "hello" div.

**Currently:**

hello

secondLine thirdLine

**Desired:**

hello secondLine thirdLine

```
<div style={{ textAlign: "left", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
        <div style={{ display: "inline" }}>
            <div>hello</div>
        </div>
        {` `}
        <div style={{ display: "inline" }}> secondDiv </div>
        <div style={{ display: "inline" }}> thirdDiv </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you don't have access to the 'hello' div, then I don't think this is possible with styles alone. If you could use CSS, you could have the "inline" div use an .inline class and have `.inline div { display: inline; }` to get past the automatic `display:block` that is likely happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the outer div display: 'flex'

```
<div style={{ textAlign: "left", whiteSpace: "nowrap",display:"flex" }}>
    <div style={{ display: "inline" }}>
        <div>hello</div>
    </div>
    { }
    <div style={{ display: "inline" }}> secondDiv </div>
    <div style={{ display: "inline" }}> thirdDiv </div>
</div>
```

For more reference :[details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

if you have access and can change the HTML change the inner `<div>` to `<span>` or any inline element, the parent div have `display:inline` and inner div will take full width ignoring parent having inline display, because the inner div have default display block:

```html
<div style="textAlign:left, whiteSpace:nowrap">
    <div style="display:inline">
        <span style="display:inline">hello</span>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline"> secondDiv </div>
    <div style="display:inline"> thirdDiv </div>
</div>
```

for your jsx code it should be like:

```
<div style={{ textAlign: "left", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
  <div style={{ display: "inline" }}>
    <span>hello</span>
  </div>
  {` `}
  <div style={{ display: "inline" }}> secondDiv </div>
  <div style={{ display: "inline" }}> thirdDiv </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this would work but I would rather not set the styles for the inner divs since they are being generated by another independent component.